# Can't call methods in contract via Web3.js

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I'm created a smart contract with ERC20 protocol and deployed in ropsten test network using RemixIDE. Now I want to show amount of custom token in my wallet on frontend, but when I trying to call to balanceOf function I'm getting error.

My code:

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
```

Getting this console error:

> Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.

I just started in blockchain development, so I'm quite newbee, my question is:
Can I actually work on this testnet(ropsten) for custom token functions?